# Blank Screen in OpenGL and Glut

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

When attempting to draw a cube, I get, instead, a blank screen. It is a screen with the background of my `glClearColor`.

My code is in so many files that I can't really post it all here, so I've placed it [on Github](http://github.com/CosineGaming/CodeIndigo). You'll want to look at it. It's a visual studio 2012 file but all the source is there for any IDE. Though very incomplete, here are some snippets:

**EDIT:** I am now able to see my shapes, but they are completely lightless. Even when I use the already made normals in `glutSolidTeapot`, it looks flat. Also, even though I specify far cutting plane to be 1000, my shapes disappear far before that. I've updated my code to be more recent.

CodeIndigo.cpp

```
// Entry point!
// Code indigo is a 3d mystery game. Readme for more information.

#include "CodeIndigo.h"
#include <iostream>


void box_update (const int& frame, const Object& self)
{
    return;
}

void update (int frame)
{
    if (Indigo::keys ['w'])
    {
        Indigo::Current_World.camera.Move (0.05);
    }
    if (Indigo::keys ['s'])
    {
        Indigo::Current_World.camera.Move (-0.05);
    }
    if (Indigo::keys ['a'])
    {
        Indigo::Current_World.camera.Move (0.0, -0.05);
    }
    if (Indigo::keys ['d'])
    {
        Indigo::Current_World.camera.Move (0.0, 0.05);
    }
    if (GL_NO_ERROR != glGetError ())
    {
        std::cout << "Error: " << glGetError () << std::endl;
    }
    if (Indigo::keys ['3'])
    {
        Camera camera = Indigo::Current_World.camera;
        std::cout << camera.X << ", " << camera.Y << ", " << camera.Z << " looking at "
            << camera.eye.Get_X () << ", " << camera.eye.Get_Y () << ", " << camera.eye.Get_Z () << std::endl;
    }
}

void mouse_moved (int x, int y)
{
    static const float sensitivity = 0.5;
    Indigo::Current_World.camera.eye.Add_Direction (0.0, x * sensitivity,
        y * -1 * sensitivity);
    std::cout << x << ", " << y << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    Indigo::Initialize (argc, argv, " ~ Code Indigo",
        800, 600, true, 60, Indigo::Sky_Color, 60);
    Mesh box = Mesh::Sphere (0.5);
    Object add = Object(0.0, 0.0, -1.0, box, Indigo::White_Color, 40.0f, box_update);
    int object = Indigo::Current_World.Add_Object (add);
    Indigo::Update_Function = update;
    Indigo::Relative_Mouse_Moved_Function = mouse_moved;
    Indigo::Current_World.lighting.Add_Light (0.0, 2.0, 0.0);
    Indigo::Current_World.camera.Place (0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    Indigo::Current_World.camera.eye.Set_Direction (1.0, 90.0, -2.8);
    Indigo::Run ();
    return (0);
}
```

Indigo::Initialize

```
// Initializes window and rendering matrices.
void Initialize (int argc, char ** argv, const char * window_name,
    const int& window_width, const int& window_height, const bool& fullscreen,
    int field_of_view, float * background, int max_framerate)
{
    glutInit (&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize (window_width, window_height);
    glutCreateWindow (window_name);
    if (fullscreen)
    {
        glutFullScreen ();
    }
    if (background)
    {
        glClearColor (background [0], background [1], background [2], 1.0);
    }
    else
    {
        glClearColor (Sky_Color [0], Sky_Color [1], Sky_Color [2], 1.0);
    }
    Frame_Length_Minimum = 1000 / max_framerate;
    glutSetKeyRepeat (GLUT_KEY_REPEAT_OFF);
    glutDisplayFunc (Render);
    glutTimerFunc (10, Update, 0);
    glutReshapeFunc (Reshape);
    glutPassiveMotionFunc (Mouse_Moved);
    glutMouseFunc (Mouse_Button);
    glutKeyboardFunc (Key_Pressed);
    glutKeyboardUpFunc (Key_Released);
    glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);
    Reshape ();
    glMatrixMode (GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity ();
    glShadeModel (GL_SMOOTH);
    glEnable (GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    return;
}
```

Indigo::Reshape

```
// Acts for when the window reshapes
void Reshape (int width, int height)
{
    bool viewport = true;
    if (0 == width)
    {
        width = glutGet (GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH);
        viewport = false;
    }
    if (0 == height)
    {
        height = glutGet (GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT);
        viewport = false;
    }
    if (viewport)
    {
        glViewport (0, 0, width, height);
    }
    glLoadIdentity ();
    gluPerspective (Field_Of_View,
        (float) width / (float) height,
        0.5, 1000.0);
}
```

World::Render

```
void World::Render (void) const
{
    // Renders every object in the world
    glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);
    Indigo::Reshape ();
    glMatrixMode (GL_MODELVIEW);
    camera.Look ();
    lighting.Position_Lights ();
    // <DELETE>
    float full_array [] = {1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0};
    glMaterialfv (GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, full_array);
    glMaterialfv (GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SPECULAR, full_array);
    glMaterialf (GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SHININESS, 60.0);
    glutSolidTeapot (0.3);
    // </DELETE>
    for (int Object_ID=0; Object_ID<objects.size (); ++Object_ID)
    {
        const_cast <Object&> (objects [Object_ID]).Render ();
    }
    glutSwapBuffers ();
    return;
}
```

Object::Render

```
// Renders the object
void Object::Render (void) const
{
    float full_array [] = {1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0};
    glMaterialfv (GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, object_color ? object_color : full_array);
    glMaterialfv (GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SPECULAR, full_array);
    glMaterialf (GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SHININESS, object_shine);
    glPushMatrix ();
    glTranslatef (X, Y, Z);
    std::vector <Vertex> points = Data.Get_Vertices ();
    glBegin (Render_Types [Data.Group_Size]);
    for (int Point=0; Point<points.size (); Point++)
    {
        // When each polygon is finished, calculate a light normal
        if ((Point + 1) % (Data.Group_Size == 0 ? 3 : Data.Group_Size) == 0)
        {
            Vertex two = points [Point - 1] - points [Point - 2];
            Vertex three = points [Point] - points [Point - 2];
            glNormal3f (two.Z * three.Y - two.Y * three.Z,
                two.X * three.Z - two.Z * three.X,
                two.Y * three.X - two.X * three.Y);
        }
        Vertex Cursor = points [Point];
        glVertex3f (Cursor.X, Cursor.Y, Cursor.Z);
    }
    glEnd ();
    glPopMatrix ();
    return;
}
```

Sorry for too much code!

The difficulty is that I don't know whether the problem lies in my:

- Setting up of the projection matrix with `gluPerspective`
- Some Glut thing I don't know about
- Drawing the shape
- Anything else

Comment: 12mb attached file? That's a no-go. How about you try and place your drawing-related code here? A single file is more than enough for a simple operation such as drawing a cube.

Comment: The trouble here is that I've created a very OOP framework and the cube is simply a test. I have just replaced the download to not include the executables and solution files that I didn't know would be so big. It's now 13 KB. I've edited the question to include some snippets for convenience, also. Thanks for the tip-off on the file size.

Comment: You've got way too much code already written for something you didn't even try to render a cube with.  It's usually better to approach this kind of stuff more incrementally.

Comment: What are the contents of Render_Types[] struct?

Comment: Render_Type to make it easier to specify the number of vertices per face. Therefore it is defined as: `const int Object::Render_Types [5] = {GL_POLYGON, 0, 0, GL_TRIANGLES, GL_QUADS};`

Comment: Please share a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/) if you really want help.

Comment: By the way, in creating the short/etc. example, you'll quite likely uncover the source of your problem.

Comment: It won't really help but you should have a look at SFML, it seems to be what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: If you have too many classes and function, then there is a problem troubleshooting errors and pinpointing where the problem might be. My suggestion is that, it would be a good idea to comment out all the function and classes that you do not need or that are yet to be tested. Then run classes and function that you need to run. By Commenting out, you will narrow down where the error is coming from. It is very easy too, to have multiple instance trying to write, read and clear the screen at the same time. Run one instance at a time and see what you are missing or what you need to code.

Comment: Why aren't you normalizing your normals in `Object::Render()`?

Comment: A good example would help a lot, you can find it in the following link, and for the beginners, it is a great place to start with. [The NeHe homepage](http://nehe.gamedev.net/) Especially, check out this particular sample [How to apply simple lighting to your scene](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/texture_filters,_lighting_&_keyboard_control/15002/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem was that I hadn't enabled `GL_LIGHTING` correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with pwny. too much of untested code. Usual causes:

1. bad camera/object position
2. wrong frustrum/perspective (bad `znear` or `zfar`)
3. enabled textures without using them
4. improper lighting/material parameters
5. forgotten to set `glColor`

to check for what is wrong

1. disable `GL_CULL_FACE,GL_DEPTH_TEST,GL_TEXTURE_1D,2D`,...lighting,material,blend
2. set projection (`GL_PROJECTION`), camera and model (`GL_MODELVIEW`) to defined state (unit matrix for example)
3. try to render `GL_QUAD` without `GL_CULL_FACE` at the right position and size to be visible
4. after success set projection matrix to perspective

   tweak `znear,zfar` and quad position to match your scene
5. replace quad with your cube
6. after success re-enable all what you need incrementally

**PS.** also good idea is to check for glerrors (may be wrong something entirely else)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm not exactly sure if this is supposed to help my lighting, because that is the main problem I have. I have checked error logs and don't get anything. Yes, I really should have placed things in classes later. The trouble is that with any of that code missing, nothing could be tested. Do you have any suggestions that may help with the lighting?

Comment: well the obvious is to check if you have good normals (sometimes they can be inverted ... which causes usually black color)